# Ellipse path not connecting properly

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to divide path on a combined path of those ellipses

[image: ellipses]

It's dividing well except for that part in the middle

[image: ellipses paths]

I want this part to be two separated parts where the red circle is

Answer (score 1):

So what I did is duplicate the part that didn't divide
Edit path, delete right side nodes, keep left side, do the same with left path and put the two new parts back where they should be